# How to change font object size in pygame

Tags: pygame

I have these code

```
FONT = pygame.font.Font("font/calibri.ttf", 50)
FONT.size = 25
```

but the compilter say

> AttributeError: 'pygame.font.FONT' object attribute 'size' is read-only

I see no method help me change size. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't change the size of an existing `Font` object. You have to create a new `Font` object with the size you want.

---

An alternative is the newer [`freetype` module](https://pyga.me/docs/ref/freetype.html). The [`render` methods](https://pyga.me/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font.render) of the `Font` class in this module support text rendering using a different size.